# Does <script><!--//--></script> have a modern purpose?

Tags: html, javascript

I'm reviewing some html produced by an outside shop.

They use comments inside their external script loading tags - so far as i'm aware this was only useful for very old javascript unaware browsers is there any modern function for this or is it redundant?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/file.js"><!--//--></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the habit has not had any grounds for a *long* time. It was meant to deal with browsers like Netscape 1. Check out e.g. these history notes: http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm

Comment: Just to add, CDATA sections do not have a use in HTML either (only in XHTML).